# Exception Value: no such table: example_post

Tags: python, django

I have a little issue of trying the `exemple` file from https://github.com/zhebrak/django-statsy

```
OperationalError at /
no such table: example_post
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: no such table: example_post
Exception Location: /home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py in execute_sql, line 894
Python Executable:  /home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/jeremie/django-statsy',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jeremie/.virtualenvs/statsy/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jeremie/django-statsy']
Server time:    Fri, 15 Sep 2017 15:13:34 -0500
```

Here is what I have done so far :

1. `git clone https://github.com/zhebrak/django-statsy.git`
2. `mkvirtualenv statsy`
3. `cd django-statsy`
4. `workon statsy`
5. `pip install -r requirements.txt`
6. `python manage.py makemigrations`
7. `python manage.py migrate`
8. `python manage.py runserver`

I just want to enter inside the `example` file to see what type of result and test out the app itself. Why do I have the problem? Do you recommend this app if I am working in a project using `Django 1.10` and `python 2.7`?

### Update

```
┌─╼ [~/django-statsy]
└────╼ python2.7 manage.py makemigrations example
Migrations for 'example':
  example/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Post
┌─╼ [~/django-statsy]
└────╼ python2.7 manage.py migrate example
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: example
Running migrations:
  Applying example.0001_initial... OK
```

Here is the result when I ran `localhost:8000` : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kaOi.png)

How could I test out the exemple which is given?

Comment: Run `python manage.py migrate` from the example directory.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add it

Comment: That exception means that either the database doesn't exist at all or django can't connect to it for some reason - is there a db.sqlite3 file somewhere in the project directory?

Comment: In my personal project, yes, but I didn't connect the app to my project yet. I can't say if there's an db.sqlite3 file somewhere in the project directory. Maybe you could investigate the subject.

Comment: If you are setting up the example included in the project, there should have been a database file created. It wasn't from what I can see in the stack trace. If you run `git status` or ` find . -name *.sqlite3` the file should come up. If it doesn't the database doesn't exist. If it does exist, you'll need to modify the settings file in the example to make sure it's looking for the right file.

Comment: Ok, I see there exists a db.sqlite3 file. Could you suggest something to do?

Comment: @user8367474 Do you have your own app named `example` with a model named `Post` inside it? It's also possible that you haven't added your app to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file. `./makemigrations` only picks up apps that are listed there.

Comment: try **'python2.7 manage.py makemigrations example'**, and **'python2.7 manage.py migrate example'**. Also see if there is a migrations folder inside the Example app.

Comment: No, there is not migrations folder inside the Example app. Why don't you test out with the same list inside my question.

Comment: I ran through your commands, and the server is running fine without any errors.

Comment: The server worked well too till I wrote `localhost:8000` in chrome. Try that.

Comment: Yeah, in chrome the home template shows up. Did you try making migrations for a specific app like 'python2.7 manage.py makemigrations example'. I tried simply running 'python2.7 manage.py makemigrations', and it didn't work until I added 'example' at the end of the command.

Comment: I will modify my quesiton @TimothyJosephBaney. Give me two minutes.

Comment: @Franey I do have my own app named `exemple` with a model named `Post` inside it.

Comment: @TimothyJosephBaney What do you got when you load a page? Do you see a graph or something like that?

Comment: No, just an empty page with a header that says home, and a centered title that says 'no posts'

Answer (score 0):

Based on your replies in the comments, it's looking like you haven't created the `example_post` database table. You'll need to add `example` to your list of `INSTALLED_APPS` in your settings file, then run through the database migration process:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

If the `example` app isn't in `INSTALLED_APPS`, the database migration files won't be created and the table won't be created as a result.